# Fixing USB Drive & Installing Archbang

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb

I'd like to install Archbang on top of my Ubuntu installation. To do this, I reduced my [Sda5 LVM partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X158z.jpg) by 100Mb, planning on being able to add a new partition in there. This is where I hit a brick wall; not knowing what to do.

From there, I tried to install Archbang onto my USB using Startup Disk Creator software, provided with Ubuntu. Somehow, while wiping this USB, it removed all partitions, and is now only visible to the 'Disks' program. When trying to add a single partition onto it, it gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FayI.jpg) error message.

**TLDR:**  I want to create a 100Gb partition to install Archbang on on my Ubuntu 15.04 PC. I also want to make an Archbang live USB to do this. Being the incompotent mess I am, I've made this clusterf***. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that the Startup Disk Creator that comes with Ubuntu only works with the Ubuntu family. Get another programs (Unetbootin is pretty good) to do it. Did you try to recover your flash drive with GParted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are using and Arch Linux derivative I suggest you check out the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/).  The [USB flash installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media) page is really helpful for creating bootable USB drives (it works for any ISO files).  I follow the "Using dd" section. The command you use would be something to the effect of

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=/path/to/archbang.iso of=/dev/sdX && sync
```

`X` is whatever your flash drive letter is from running `lsblk

for me `lsblk` outputs

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      3:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   3:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   3:2    0 410.9G  0 part /
└─sda3   3:3    0   6.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   1.9G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   657M  0 part /media/user/ARCH_201508
└─sdb2   8:18   1    31M  0 part
```

So my flash drive is `/dev/sdb`

Comment: That just might solve the USB issue, thank you :-)

Comment: Just so you know.  The dd command will partition the flash drive a little weird.  To get it usable again follow the arch wiki again [how to restore the USB drive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#How_to_restore_the_USB_drive)

Comment: Alright, interesting reading. Again, thanks, got it working fine